# Wordpress Recent post only showing title

Tags: recent-posts

I'm new in wordpress theme development. I want to display recent posts via recent post widget. but when I active the Recent posts widget in wordpress admin panel it only shows the title but not the images. But when i write a custom code in sidebar it works fine. I want to work it like a widget perfection. 
I do not want to use any plugin, help me in custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts` class in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` to see how it is structured.

You can even copy and paste the class in your `functions.php`, rename it to something else and modify the class to display your images.

And don't forget to add a [`register_widget('NameOfYourClassHere');`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) hooked to `widgets_init`.

Comment: Thanks RRikesh. it worked on me and i also got new info about widget panel. :)